# build error came after update node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, build

`Error on fetch for node_modules/angular2-notifications/src/simple-notifications.module.js at file:///D:/GIP/IMAGE PILOT/gipfe/node_modules/angular2-notifications/src/simple-notifications.module.js
        Loading build/tmp/aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
        Loading build\boot-aot.js
        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\GIP\IMAGE PILOT\gipfe\node_modules\angular2-notifications\src\simple-notifications.module.js'
[10:13:51] 'build.aot' errored after 52 s
[10:13:51] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(bundle-aot)'
Message:
    Error on fetch for node_modules/angular2-notifications/src/simple-notifications.module.js at file:///D:/GIP/IMAGE PILOT/gipfe/node_modules/angular2-notifications/src/simple-notifications.module.js
        Loading build/tmp/aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
        Loading build\boot-aot.js
        ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\GIP\IMAGE PILOT\gipfe\node_modules\angular2-notifications\src\simple-notifications.module.js'
Details:
    originalErr: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\GIP\IMAGE PILOT\gipfe\node_modules\angular2-notifications\src\simple-notifications.module.js'
Stack:
Error on fetch for node_modules/angular2-notifications/src/simple-notifications.module.js at file:///D:/GIP/IMAGE PILOT/gipfe/node_modules/angular2-notifications/src/simple-notifications.module.js
        Loading build/tmp/aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
        Loading build\boot-aot.js
        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\GIP\IMAGE PILOT\gipfe\node_modules\angular2-notifications\src\simple-notifications.module.js'`

```
import { SimpleNotificationsModule }                from 'angular2-notifications';
 imports: [
    SharedModule,
    routing,
    ToastModule.forRoot(),
    SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot(),
```

this build error came when i take build **npm run build.aot** command. i put **npm install** command in my project then i try to take build error was came.

pls help me to resolve this

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before i installed typescript version

```
"typescript": "^2.3.3" // package.json
```

then i changed the typescript version

```
"typescript": "2.3.3" //without cap symbol
```

Now,error was not came and i took build successfully